# How can i go ahead to configure two subnetted networks to apache so as to create two lone networks that are connected via switch?

Tags: windows, active-directory, network-protocols

I want to connect 15 systems to a server so that they do not communicate among themselves directly but do so via server, how should i go ahead?

i need to allot say 5 systesm to HR people and 5 other systems to IT people..and network them in such a way that they are not able to even PING each other,,,now they all need to be connected to a central server for respective roamning profiles of the users of respective systems hence how do i go on to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either setup ever computer in it's own vLAN (separate subnets and all), or configure IPSec.

Seriously, if your network needs security such that computers can't even communicate with each other, you're probably better off hiring a consultant who knows what they're doing to configure it for you. You're likely to end up in a situation where a very small misconfiguration results in communication still being allowed.

Comment: Thanx ,that does throw some light on the solution.Thank you